# <script src="js/jquery/jquery.js"></script> is NOT loading from HTML file but @import for css file is

Tags: javascript, html, ubuntu

So here I have a basic HTML file using Ubuntu on a VMWare Fusion VM on a MACBOOK pro.

Here's the BASIC file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/import.css" media="all" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hello World</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

OK, so I've been developing for over 20 years and I've just started using the following with the job I'm at:

- MAC OSX
- VMWare Fusion on the MAC for Ubuntu (1st Time ever using this and I LOVE IT
- Redis Server (Ah, not so much)
- Node.js
- Grunt
- Karma

And so the list goes on...

My PATH is /home/myusername/inetpub/wwwroot/myprojectdir/

My server URL is simply: localhost in the browser
I'm using Netbeans 8.0

When I run the file, above, the console log shows that the CSS files have loaded nicely, but, and this is REALLY strange; the JS files do not load at all.

This is the strange part:

When I do a simple CSS load like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/import.css" media="all" />
```

The import.css file is simply this:

```
@import "style.css"
```

That works, but; when I try to load the style.css file the NORMAL way, like this;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="all" />
```

I get a page 404 error NOT found.

I've tried preloading the javascript files like the @import for the CSS but to no avail.

This is completely mind-boggling.

So in SUMMARY:

THIS WORKS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script> <--- DOES NOT WORK
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script> <--- DOES NOT WORK
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/import.css" media="all" /> <--- WORKS as long as I use @import within the import.css file.
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hello World</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but THIS does not:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script> <--- DOES NOT WORK
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script> <--- DOES NOT WORK 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="all" /> <--- DOES NOT WORK
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hello World</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What's the problem here??? PLEASE HELP!

UPDATE:

Here's the screenshot of the CONSOLE LOG....  Look at the way all the CSS files are loaded and not the JS files.... remember, I'm on Ubuntu 14.01 LTS on a VM through a MAC Book Pro OSX 10.94

[image]

Comment: what about `/css/style.css` or `/myprojectdir/css/style.css`? maybe the target browser doesn't load the js files.

Comment: Tried it...no joy.  SEE UPDATE for further details

Comment: Console log in your web inspector says nothing about 404 error. 404 will look like `GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/wdcwdcvwev.min.js 404 (Not Found)`. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE most likely says "server got request, but closed connection without write some bytes in answer". This can be server configuration issue or bug

Comment: very interesting since I'm using REDIS as the server via TERMINAL (HATE IT) I'm a Windows guy forced to use a Ubuntu on a MAC via VMWare Fusion... what a cluster<insert colorful metaphor here>!  Bottom line, I looked in /etc/redis/redis.conf and all it says is: localhost. REALLY helpful.

Comment: @Peter maybe you don't have permission of the given file, or the server cannot access it. make sure it's accessible by either run the server from the user owns the file or permits it for the server.

Comment: @Peter checks the server logs, this will help alot of course

Comment: All, here's what's happened. Today, after firing up my MAC and restarting VMWare/Ubuntu, everything simply fell into place with no issues. AMAZING what happens when you do the equivalent of the "Three Fingered Salute" on a MAC.  So in SUM, I'm sorry to have taken up everyone's time on something so simple as "restarting" the machine. Another "Homer Simpson" moment. D'oh!  So how to grant credits, up-votes to you all for helping? Someone/everyone deserves the credit.... Seriously. Thank you!